# Route TCP responses (ACK) through another interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tcp

For reasons I can't go into, I am working with a strange network configuration.

I have a one-way higher speed wireless link, and a slower bi-directional wireless link.  There is a network interface for each link (currently only UDP works on the one way link).

My goal is to route all returning traffic (like TCP responses) from the one-way link over the bi-directional link.

Is this possible?  The network interfaces on both ends of the wireless links are currently on Linux based PCs.

Comment: I don't understand... are there two wireless links on one linux workstation, or two wireless links spread across two linux workstations?

Comment: Both ends have two wireless links on one linux box.

Comment: Are these 802.11 wireless links or something else? There are rules beyond just routing that you have to follow on many such links. Are the wireless links themselves routed? Or do they emulate a bridged network?

Comment: The wireless links use HDLC. They are direct serial connections with a networking interface layer on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with default gateways and static routes.

Here's a how to that should help since you didn't specify any particular OS: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/